# Express-session Empty Session

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, session-cookies, express-session

I am just starting to learn how to use cookies with node and express and I would like some help with getting this to work. and I m working on an SSO project,  so I had to set a session cookie with  `sameSite:'none'`attribute so I can share session with other projects

```
var newUserSession = session({
secret: 'mfkmjgik',

store: new RedisStore({
  port: 9090,
  client: client,
  ttl: 260
}),
cookie: {
  sameSite: 'none',
  secure: false,
  maxAge: 36000
},
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false
})
```

the problem is when I added sameSite to session cookie I m getting an empty session,

```
Session {
cookie:
 { path: '/',
   _expires: 2020-03-24T10:19:57.764Z,
   originalMaxAge: 36000,
   httpOnly: true,
   sameSite: 'none',
   secure: false 
  }
}
```

> but This happen only in chrome browser it works really fine in opera and firefox

All help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before February  the Chrome SameSite cookie default was : “None,” which allows third-party cookies to track users across sites. But from February, cookies are default into “SameSite=Lax,” which means cookies are only set when the domain in the URL of the browser matches the domain of the cookie — a first-party cookie

Comment: @AdeelNawaz yaa exactly , but any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: @AdeelNawaz I added  domain: 'localhost' to the session but it still the same problem

Comment: define path as well `path: '/',`

Comment: @AdeelNawaz still same :(